# Making the grid system in CSS responsive for mobile devices

Tags: html, css, html5-canvas

I am making my grid system in CSS. I had written the following code for it and it is working fine. But i want to know how to make this layout responsive for mobile devices less than 600px. The code snippet is shown below.

```
.grid-container {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: auto;
}

/*-- our cleafix hack -- */
.row:before,.row:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}

[class*='col-'] {
    float: left;
    min-height: 1px;
    width: 16.66%;
    /*-- our gutter -- */
    padding: 12px;
    background-color: #FFDCDC;
}

.col-1 {
    width: 16.66%;
}

.col-2 {
    width: 31%;
}

.col-3 {
    width: 48%;
}

.col-4 {
    width: 66.66%;
}

.col-5 {
    width: 83.33%;
}

.col-6 {
    width: 100%;
}

.outline,.outline * {
    outline: 1px solid #F6A1A1;
}

/*-- some extra column content styling --*/
[class*='col-']>p {
    background-color: #FFC2C2;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
}`enter code here`
```

Please help me out.

Comment: have you done any research or searching for responsive CSS? The term "media queries" should help

Comment: I am new to web development. I was told to use % instead of px to make the website responsive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make it work on different sizes you must use media queries. 
More info: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

At the moment i know about two methods of work:

1) **Class manipulation**: overwrite class attributes where media query is matched, ex:

```
 @media only screen and (max-width: 600px)  {    //apply if screen is < 600px
      .col-5 { width: 50% }       // overwrite the width of 83.33% to 50%
 }
```

In html it would like as **class="col-5"**

*Advantages*: simpler to maintain, just one class to add

*Disadvantages*: you cant set different size for every screen-width

---

2) **Different classes** for different sizes and dives like :

```
 @media only screen and (max-width: 600px)  {    //apply if screen is < 600px
      .col-mob-3 { width: 50% }   //only if the max-width < 600 set attr
 }
```

In html it would like for example as **class="col-5 col-mob-3"**

*Advantages*: you can even change the size on every breakpoint

*Disadvantages*: most verbose

---

**Common breakpoints for me are:**

**- up to 320 ? mob portrait** : @media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {}

**- up to 480 ? mob landscape** : @media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {}

**- up to 680 ? mini tab + landscape** : @media only screen and (max-width: 680px) {}

**- up to 810 ? Tablets and Facebook** : @media only screen and (max-width: 810px) {}

**- up to 1024 ? Computer** : @media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {}

**- over to 1280 ? Large screen** : @media only screen and (max-width: 1280px) {}

Here an example : http://socialtab.it/beta/chiusagrande/public/css/grid.css

For others are : http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

---

**Tips:**

Use % when possible, it will look better. Set `max-width: 100%` on columns to prevent overflow if you are using "pixel" grid (not %, fluid). For the container i love this set:

```
.container {
   width: 1060px;
   max-width: 96%;
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```

I'm just learning as you :D

Sorry for bad English, I've tried my best D:

Comment: If you have any questions ( yes, you have :/ ) i will gladly help you tomorrow, now i going to sleep :D

Answer (score 0):

```
    /* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 321px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (max-width : 320px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : landscape) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : portrait) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Desktops and laptops ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 1224px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Large screens ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 1824px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPhone 4 ----------- */
@media
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5),
only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5) {
/* Styles */
}
```